# Is there any way to unshorten the url using pure javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm looking for a method through which I can get the unshortened URL of a shorten URL which I input in my javascript file.

```js
function(short_url){ 
some method; 
return full_url; 
}
```

like I would call a function and pass a shortened URL of bitly through it and it will return me the full URL. what will be the method or process should I use

I'm using simple hosting for this code so can't use node.js

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean by "short url"?

Comment: @paulsm4 — They gave the example of https://bitly.com/ in the question. They are asking about third-party short URL redirection services.

Comment: @paulsm4 like any shorten url service we use like google shortner or bitly shortner

Comment: Bitly has an api you can use https://dev.bitly.com/api-reference#getBitlink. Look at the `fetch()` code samples which @Quentin most likely assumed didn't exists for browser.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you can't use Node.js, I assume you mean "With JS running in the browser".

**No**.

You would need an API that would allow you to make an HTTP request to a URL that has a redirect response and then read the `Location` header from it.

This will fail for two reasons:

1. The APIs browsers provide to JS for making HTTP requests follow redirects **transparently** so you can never read the Location header.
2. They would be cross-origin requests and would be blocked by the Same Origin Policy in most cases.

Sime short URL servers display an interstitial HTML document telling the user that they are being redirected. In those cases, problem 1 goes away and, if it weren't for problem 2 still affecting this, you would need to write a custom parser for each service's HTML document to extract the target URL from.

Comment: yes I tried this do send a http request to the shortened url and in most of the cases i got the cors error

Comment: @AmanDutt - Yes, as I said, that is one of the two things that makes what you want to do impossible.

Comment: any other way you can suggest through which I can do this?